# Cameras for automatic customer service machine

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, image-classification, image-recognition, project-planning

For my university project, I am planning to build an automated customer service machine. One which recognizes when someone approaches the camera according to says hello, etc.

Also, I am planning to add simple speech recognition and language processing features. So my question is.

What kind of camera would be suitable? Is there any particular model that you recommend. I was thinking of cameras used for amazon go(as an example).

Comment: Welcome to the site. Selection of right camera is probably beyond the scope of this site.